To fetch bytes sent/received per sec for particular application
Need to find amount of incoming outgoing network bytes using cmd/powershell command for specific application.
So I researched and found that there isn't any direct way to filter this data using netsat/various other network commands or the powershell counters. You can find bytes sent/received per second for the system but not for any application.
ALthough there were multiple pages which led me to log through ETW logs/trace session. I was using provider: Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network to filter data sent and data received Opcodes, but I noticed all of them were for the system's processId and not for any application/other services. Can anyone help me through this? Or suggest a different provider for it.
Below is the powershell code I tried
$log_path = "<Your_log_location"
$filterXML = '*[System[Opcode = 11 or Opcode = 27 or Opcode = 43 or Opcode = 59]]'
logman create trace "KernelNetworkTraceSession2" -p "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network" -o $log_path -ets
logman stop "KernelNetworkTraceSession2" -ets
Get-WinEvent -Path $log_path -Oldest -FilterXPath $filterXML -MaxEvents 10  | Format-List -Property *


You can use Wireshark or Fiddler to get times of messages.  There is no command that will monitor transfer rates using PS.

@jdweng
Transfer rates or the total traffic?
The time is not the biggest question here. The biggest question is how to get the traffic for a particular application

You question is confusing because you are asking multiple questions.  What do you really need to do?   Get-WinEvent will only give Windows System Events and not Applications.  You either need to capture logs for your application or use a sniffer tool (wireshark or fiddler) to capture the network data.

The provider Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP gives you accurate information. See https://github.com/Siemens-Healthineers/ETWAnalyzer/blob/main/ETWAnalyzer/Documentation/DumpTCPCommand.md what you can get. WPA (Windows Performance Analyzer) can show you send/receive rates, tcp retransmits and more. For connection resets I am right now adding support to ETWAnalyzer.
